# Cloud Foundry: How do I get the contents of the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable? (and only this variable!)

Tags: sed, environment-variables, zsh, cloud-foundry

When I deploy an app to Cloud Foundry and attach it to instances of Cloud Foundry services,
and I use the Cloud Foundry CLI to get the environment variables: `cf env my-app`,
then I get an output like:

```
Getting env variables for app my-app in org my-org / space my-space as user@company.com...
System-Provided:
VCAP_SERVICES: {
 "service1": [
   // ...
 ],
 "service2": [
   // ...
 ]
}

VCAP_APPLICATION: {
 // ...
}

User-Provided:
VARIABLE1: value
VARIABLE2: value

Running Environment Variable Groups:
CREDHUB_API: https://credhub.company.com

No staging env variables have been set
```

How do I filter this output to get only the contents of the environment variable `VCAP_SERVICES`, so that when I test/debug my app locally, it behaves as if it was attached to the instances of the Cloud Foundry services?

My goal is to write a file named `default-env.json` containing only:

```
{
 VCAP_SERVICES: {
  "service1": [
    // ...
  ],
  "service2": [
    // ...
  ]
 }
}
```

Ideally, the command to produce this output should be a zsh one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

```
cf env my-app | sed -n '/VCAP_SERVICES/,/VCAP_APPLICATION/p' |  sed '$d' |  sed '1s;^;{\n;' | sed '$s/$/}/' > default-env.json
```

**Explanation**

1. `sed -n '/VCAP_SERVICES/,/VCAP_APPLICATION/p'`
   keeps only the section between the regular expressions `VCAP_SERVICES` and `VCAP_APPLICATION`.
2. `sed '$d'` deletes the last line (the line containing `VCAP_APPLICATION`).
3. `sed '1s;^;{\n;'` prepends `{\n` to the first line.
4. `sed '$s/$/}/'` appends `}` to the end of the file.

**Credits**

- [Handy one-liners for SED](https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/sed-oneliners.html)
- [BASH Prepend A Text / Lines To a File](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-prepend-text-lines-to-file/)
- [SED: insert text after the last line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20574)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be:

```
cf curl "/v2/apps/$(cf app --guid my-super-cool-app)/env" | jq -r '.system_env_json.VCAP_SERVICES'
```

Explanation:

1. `$(cf app --guid <your-app-name)` will run in a subshell and get the app guid for your app. You could alternatively just replace that bit with the guid for your app, if you know it already (it'll make the command faster).
2. `cf curl "/v2/apps/<guid>/env"` will return all of the env variables for your app.
3. `jq -r '.system_env_json.VCAP_SERVICES'` picks out the bit you want.

You could optionally redirect output to a file.

Other interesting bits from that API:

- `.application_env_json.VCAP_APPLICATION` would give you `VCAP_APPLICATION`.
- `'.environment_json'` would give you any env variables you've set

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Unfortunately it means I have to install the external binary jq, which makes it less suitable for my use case.